# Weird behaviour in VS 2013 during debugging

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

during debugging in Visual Studion 2013, for a C# project, the yellow arrow that appears next to the line number does not move to the next line.
I have to press F10 twice on every line.
When there is a method call and I press F11, it goes to that method and then jumps back to the calling part on pressing F10, I have to press F10 again a second time only then it goes back to the next line in the called method.

What is going on?
Did I accidentally turn on/off some setting in VS?

Please help as this is causing a lot of frustration.

Regards.

Comment: Are you debugging a multithreaded app?, check your `Threads` window, you might have multiple threads calling the same method, hence why you get the feeling of "pressing twice" on the same method.

Comment: This happens when your program is running on more than one thread. You run through the execution of both threads, and sometimes you need to just from one place to another, if the threads are running different parts of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're debugging a MultiThreaded app, which is accessing the same method multiple times, as i said in the comments.

Check your `Threads` window and you will see that more then 1 Thread is accessing the called method, and that's why you're experiencing having to press F10 more then once, and why F11 is returning back to the called method.

Inside your `Threads` window, you can Freeze threads by right clicking them and pressing "Freeze".

Comment: Do I select each thread and select 'Freeze'? That's a lot of work to do while debugging as I see there are quite a few threads running.

Comment: You can freeze only those `Threads` that call your specific method.
If there are too many threads open, i'd start looking into why instead of just freezing them in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

As suggest in Yuval's answer, It seems this issue happens due to multiple threads.
Lucky for you, It is very simple to test that. All you have to do is:

For each thread, assign a unique name when it is created. This could be done by something like the following after creation:

```
if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Thread.CurrentThread.Name))
{
   Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "MyThread_" + id++;
}
```

Don't forget to add:

```
using System.Threading
```

In your `Watch` window add a record for `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name`.
Now all that is left, is to check if the value of that record changes every time you press `F10`